# Android, when is the ViewPager ready? Overlapping fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Ive got a problem with overlapping fragments which I am unable to resolve. When I first start the activity, the order of the fragments is mixed up. As soon as I begin sliding, everything works fine. Basically, I need to find a way to react on every GPFragment called onCreateView... for example I just can call onPageSelected(0) on the adapter, but this only fixes the problem after all views are created! How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

I have this in onCreate of the FragmentActivity

```
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);

    adapter = new GPPagerAdapter(this, this.getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(adapter);

    pager.setCurrentItem(0);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);

    pager.setPageMargin(-500);
```

Then I have in the Adapter:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    position = position % GamePickerActivity.GAMECOUNT;

    PGCGames game = PGCGames.fromNo(position + 1);

    Fragment frag = GPFragment.newInstance(context, position, scale, game.getDrawable(), game.getText());
    return frag;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    // viewCollection.put(position, fragment.getView());
    Object o = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    fragmentCollection.put(position, (GPFragment) o);
    return o;
}
```

This is actually the point, here I arrange the views, so that the chosen one is in the front! This works perfectly fine AFTER all the fragments called their onCreateView-method

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    View view = getViewFromFragmentSafe(fragmentCollection.get(position));
    if (view != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            View otherView = getViewFromFragmentSafe(fragmentCollection.get(i));
            if (otherView != null)
                otherView.bringToFront();
        }
        for (int i = fragmentCollection.size(); i > position; i--) {
            View otherView = getViewFromFragmentSafe(fragmentCollection.get(i));
            if (otherView != null)
                otherView.bringToFront();
        }

        view.bringToFront();
        context.gameSet(position);
    }
}
```

Then my GPFragment class:
    public static Fragment newInstance(GamePickerActivity context, int pos, float scale, int drawable, int textResource) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("pos", pos);
        b.putInt("text", textResource);
        b.putInt("drawable", drawable);
        b.putFloat("scale", scale);
        return Fragment.instantiate(context, GPFragment.class.getName(), b);
    }

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    ...

    GPLinearLayout root = (GPLinearLayout) l.findViewById(R.id.root);
    float scale = this.getArguments().getFloat("scale");
    root.setScaleBoth(scale);

    return l;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what your onPageSelected() is supposed to do, but it is called very early on as you actively call pager.setCurrentItem(0). What if you ignore the onPageSelected() code the first time it is called? Not that I'm sure but just have a hunch that this is where your problem is. A simple boolean would do.

Comment: my onPageSelected() actually brings the "middle" fragment to the front and all the others to the back in the right order! This already works fine. Exactly this method should be called once again, after all the fragments and their views are created, and everything would be fine! btw. youre right, setCurrentItem is called early, thats why there are null-checks in onPageSelected necessary.

Comment: Just to test the idea, try making a 1-2 second delay before calling setCurrentItem(0) to confirm that it works